# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 379: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: ascii

I created an e-mail address, but when trying to check from the e-mail listing menu, I get the following error

‘ascii’ codec can’t decode byte 0xc4 in position 379: ordinal not in range(128)
my ubuntu version 20.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlG3b.jpg)

Comment: please, specify your ubuntu version

Comment: my ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: First of all; `ASCII` has no codes above 127 / decimal, 0x7f / hexadecimal. Now, for anybody to be able to get this thing any further you need to present more detail about what you have done / what software you're trying to use / how things are set up. (What I see above indicates trouble possible in e.g. Python code)

Comment: I installed cyberpanel 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 20.04